# Howto put load on a database server (mysqld.exe)

Tags: mysql

Is there a strategy to keep mysqld.exe busy? For testing purposes I have to generate a negative situation in which mysqld.exe is busy or unresponsive so the system under test has to kill it.

Comment: You have the wrong approach here. I'm working as a database admin for several years now and it is my job to never ever have to "kill" the database. You don't want to do that. Sure, MySQL does what it can to ensure acid compliance, but some broken tables or something you don't want to have that. This can easily result in several hours of downtime, or a whole day to restore a backup (depending on how much data you have of course). My advice, you should rather have someone with decent knowledge who can solve the problem of the load by killing the right transaction or whatever the problem is.

Comment: to add to @fancyPants comment.. if a MySQL server becomes unresponsive for example running badly optimized queries.. login with a user that has SUPER privilege (most likely only root account)  use `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST`, copy paste the query from processlist and run `EXPLAIN <query>` then you can use `KILL <proces_id>` to make the MySQL respond again.. If you use `EXPLAIN <query>`  it not really needed but you can see what wrong with the query so you can optimize it with indexes so it won't happen again..

Answer (score 1):

There is a tool for this called `mysqlslap`.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqlslap.html